# How to run git command in full path?

Tags: windows, git, cmd, path

As usually,we can use `git status`.But under some reasons,the cmd can't recognize `git`.So I need to use full path.Run `where git`,I got this:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
```

How to use git full path?

Comment: what do you mean by 'How to use git full path?'

Comment: well.If I calling the cmd manually,`git status` wordks.But If I calling the cmd in a program,the cmd shows `can't recognize git`,Someone suggest me use full path

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to run git and do not have it in your PATH, just use:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe" status
```

Answer (score 1):

Like I stated in your other questions, you can handle everything like before.

```
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe status
```

Creates the same output as

```
git status
```

Ofc when you run it in the cmd you have to use `"` since the Path to the `.exe` contains whitespace:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe" status
```

Comment: But the words Program Files contains a blank.The cmd shows can't recognize C:\Program(My cmd is Chinese version,Idk the correct words in English).

Comment: Yeah you have to use `"` to address a Path including whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `git status` with `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe status`

Or in general replace `git ...` with `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe ...`